# java.lang.IllegalAccessError triggering due to the class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView is inaccessible

Tags: android, proguard, android-appcompat, minify, androidx

I have recently changed the Android target SDK version from 29 to 30. Now I am getting a new crash which says the following

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface androidx.core.widget.l implemented by class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView is inaccessible (declaration of 'androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView' appears in /data/app/co.udhaar.app-aPVvUdO7b4lt8gLmAiy5kA==/base.apk)
```

stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface androidx.core.widget.l implemented by class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView is inaccessible (declaration of 'androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView' appears in /data/app/co.udhaar.app-aPVvUdO7b4lt8gLmAiy5kA==/base.apk)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1527)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:2757)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2791)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2858)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2167)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:864)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
   at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
   at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
   at co.udhaar.app.ui.splashScreen.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:78)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
   at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3531)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Gradle version:

```
6.5
```

Gradle plugin

```
4.0.0
```

Following are the androidx dependencies in my project

```
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.2"
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"
```

I am stuck on this issue. It will be great if you guys can shed some light. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not a real answer but maybe a workaround, have you tried to use the `ImageView`? The `AppCompatImageView` doc says "This will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views." here's the source: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatImageView

Comment: @JoséFernandoGarciaJunior Sorry missed to mention. I am already using ImageView in my layout

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this has been resolved.
I just added this line of code to proguard-rules.pro file:

-keep class androidx.appcompat.** { *; }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will definitely work, I've already fixed it by adding -keep class androidx.appcompat.** { *; } into the Proguard Rules. But I don’t think this is an answer rather than a workaround. I do not know what is leading to this and why the Minify is removing these classes, and it worked well on previous builds where the target API level was 29.